# .htaccess permanent redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess

I currently make use of the the following .htaccess which removes .php from the end of all urls http://littleloans.co.za/index.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I've just bought a SSL certificate and want to keep the current rules but also redirect from http to https

Any solutions for me please? Permanent redirect

Answer (score 1):

Just use this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this as the first rule should work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
#redirect http to https and www to  non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
#remove .php
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```